# Unwinding a data structure to a previous state

Tags: ds.algorithms

Suppose I have an algorithm which maintains a data structure $A$. After the algorithm has run up to time $t_2$, it decides to back-track to a prior state $t_1$. It should be possible to restore the state of $A$ to what it was at time $t_1$ by simulating $A$, instead of running it directly, and maintaining a log of all changes made to $A$. The total time needed to unwind the state of $A$ to time $t_1$ should be $O(t_2 - t_1)$, possibly with some logarithmic factors

I have a few questions about this ---

(1) Does this principle have a name?

(2) Do I have to pay logarithmic factors for simulating $A$ instead of running it? I would like to avoid this if possible. Is there a model of computation, such as the RAM model, that avoids this? Or are there some regularity conditions?

Thanks!

EDIT: Some search of the literature shows that this is called the "rollback method". It seems to be a folk theorem that the RAM model supports linear-time rollback. I am a little surprised that there is nothing proved formally and no papers cited, as (for example) the Turing Machine model requires a logarithmic slowdown.

Comment: Maybe you want to look at [persistent data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure).

Comment: This helps but doesn't address the question directly. Persistence seems to involve more general operations than simply unwinding. The theorems that are proved are not very generic. I only need to perform a single type of back-tracking, and I want to very open-ended about the data structure involved.

Comment: You need to be a little careful here: rollback doesn't mix well with amortization.